# classNotFoundException while accessing the aar file's classes in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, maven, aar, android-studio-3.5.3

I created an aar file from an module and added it to my project it got added successfully but whenever I am trying to run my app then every time it is getting crashed saying classNotFoundException.

- I tried to add dependencies in my module using implementation, api and compile (deprecated now) but still getting the same issue.
- I hosted my aar file at Maven and tried to add that dependency in my project but still no luck and getting the same error every time.

**There is a work around for the same I can add the those dependencies into my project which I added into my module but I do not want to that.**

**If I add my project as dependencies then it works fine but I do not want to that also as the module I am working on will be used by multiple clients and I do not want to share my source code with everyone.**

I am using the following:

- Android Studio 3.5.3
- Android Gradle Plugin version 3.5.3
- Gradle version 5.4.1
- Min SDK Version 21, compile SDK version 29
- JDK 8

Is there anything I am doing wrong or I am missing, any  help will be appreciated.

**Edit 1**

I am not using proguard that is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

It is related to proguard, try adding a rule to keep the class in  `proguard-rules.pro` file

```
-keep class com.app.package.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.app.package.**
```

replace 'com.app.package ' with your package (where the Notfound class exist)

Comment: But I am not using proguard, i have disabled that.

Comment: You got the crash in release or debug ?

Comment: In both I am getting the same crash.

Comment: sure I will try that

Comment: It's not working, I have to explicitly add the dependencies which I am using in aar file